# Linker error calling .mm function from .cpp file

Tags: c++, objective-c, linker, osx-lion, xcode4.6

I've added a obj-c class (.mm and 2 headers) to my current Xcode 4.6 project. One header file has the prototype to call to the obj-c class and the other defines the .mm class. Here's what it looks like.

myinterface.h

```
#ifndef MYINTERFACE_H
#define MYINTERFACE_H

BOOL LaunchApp(CAtlString exePath);

#endif
```

myLaunchClass.h

```
#import "myinterface.h"

@interface myLaunchClass : NSObject
-(BOOL) LaunchApp:(CAtlString)exePath;
@end
```

myLaunchClass.mm

```
@import "myLaunchClass.h"

@implementation myLaunchClass
-(BOOL) LaunchApp:(CAtlString)exePath
{
    ....
    return someCondition;
}
@end
```

From there it compiles good. I added the .mm file to the Target in the Build Phases and the header location to the Header Search Paths in the Build Settings.

When I include the header file in my .cpp file (`#include "myinterface.h"`) I have no errors. However, when I call my function (`::LaunchApp(exePath);`), I a linker error.

Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "LaunchApp(CAtlString)", referenced from:
      myCppFile::myCppFunction() const in myCppFile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Any ideas? I think it must be an obvious mistake for a Mac developer but I'm a bit new still with Mac programming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C++ doesn't interoperate this way. `-(BOOL)LaunchApp:(CAtlString)exePath` is declaring an instance method on an Objective-C class. That method can only ever be called from Objective-C (i.e. .m, .mm) files, and if the method signature includes C++ types (like it does here), then it can only be called from Objective-C++ (.mm) files. Furthermore, `-(BOOL)LaunchApp:(CAtlString)exePath` is an instance method, and you appear to be calling it as if it were a C++ static/class method, which won't work either.

If you want to wrap your Objective-C class to make it available to straight C++ consumers, you would have to do something like this:

**MyLaunchClass.h**:

```
#if __cplusplus
#import <string>
#endif

@interface MyLaunchClass : NSObject

#if __cplusplus
- (BOOL)launchApp: (std::string)str;
#endif

@end

#if __cplusplus

struct WrappedMyLaunchClass
{
    MyLaunchClass* mImpl;

    WrappedMyLaunchClass() : mImpl([[MyLaunchClass alloc] init]) { };

    ~WrappedMyLaunchClass() { mImpl = nil; }; // Assuming ARC here. for non-ARC, [mImpl release]

    bool LaunchApp(std::string str)
    {
        return !![mImpl launchApp:str];
    }
};

#endif
```

**MyLaunchClass.mm**:

```
#import "MyLaunchClass.h"
#import <string>

@implementation MyLaunchClass

- (BOOL)launchApp: (std::string)str
{
    NSLog(@"%s", str.c_str());
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**SomeOtherFile.cpp**:

```
void someOtherFunction()
{
    WrappedMyLaunchClass x;
    x.LaunchApp("foobar");
}
```

In sum, you are overestimating the interoperability of C++ and Objective-C++.  You can think of Objective-C++ as "Objective-C with the addition of the ability to have variables of C++ types and the ability to call C++ code" but **not** as "an alternate syntax for declaring C++ types."

**Caveat Emptor!**: This is drastically oversimplifying what would be involved in meaningfully wrapping an Objective-C object in a C++ object.  C++'s by-value/by-reference semantics are *drastically* different from Objective-C's and a naive implementation like this is going to hit all sorts of problems if the C++ object is ever passed by value (i.e. via a copy constructor) etc. I provide the example only to show why what you attempted wouldn't work, not as some kind of general purpose code for wrapping Objective-C objects in C++ objects.

Comment: Do I need the someOtherFunction in the .mm file? What would be the difference if I changed my .mm class to be more c++ like (ie: class MyLaunchClass instead of @interface MyLaunchClass)?

Comment: `someOtherFunction` can be in a .cpp file. It's not interacting directly with Objective-C++, just the straight-C++ stuff. Anything that touches Objective-C++ has to be in a .mm file. What would the difference be `class MyLaunchClass` and `@interface MyLaunchClass`? `class MyLaunchClass` would be a C++ class and would not be able to passed to traditional Objective-C API. It's probably easiest to say it like this: you can directly call straight-C++ from Objective-C++. You cannot directly call Objective-C++ from straight-C++.